# Where is updmap.cfg?

Tags: texlive, minionpro

**edit**

I found the problem and the solution: I renamed the `.pfb` files to the correct name, that is, `MinionPro-Regular.pfb`.

Please, close the post.

**edit**

I found this file here `~/.texlive2011/texmf-config/web2c` and I insert the map there. After some updates the error changed to

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file MinionPro-Regular.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
>    ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Maybe some progress.

---

I am trying to use MinionPro. I followed this [tutorial](http://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2007/12/11/installing-minion-pro-fonts/) but I don't have the file `/etc/texmf/updmap.d/10local.cfg`. I am using Lubuntu 11.10.

So I don't know where to insert the line `Map MinionPro.map`. I wrote it in

> /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg$

and after run some commands, like `updmap-sys`, when I try to compile the test I get the error

> kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+545/600 --dpi 545 MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa
>   mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa.
>   mktexpk: perhaps MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa is missing from the map file.
>   kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
>    )
>   !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa): Font MinionPro-Regula
>   r-Base-aa at 545 not found

Any help, please? Maybe I have to use another `cfg` file. Thanks.

Comment: You can try with `updmap --enable Map=MinionPro.map`

Comment: Thanks, but nothing new. I updated my post.